# S3 HTTP status 503 slow down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon documentation states that using AmazonS3Client from SDK will handle 503 Slow Down responses by backing-off and retrying.  We are seeing 503 returned occasionally when using the SDK client.
The document at https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AmazonS3BestPractices.pdf?stod_obj2 states

> While Amazon S3 is internally optimizing for a new request rate, you will receive HTTP 503 request responses temporarily until the optimization completes.

Does this mean we should implement our own back-off on top of AWS's, retry immediately as the SDK will handle it again, or we should never see 503 from the client?
EDIT: would using TransferUtility help prevent this due to it's own error handling code, or would it exacerbate it with it's aggressive uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although SDK clients have already done a good job reducing 503 errors as much as possible, 503 errors do occur especially when you have a sudden spike of traffic. There is no need to implement your own retry logic and reinvent the wheel. What happens under the hood when S3 throws 503 is that partitioning requests are triggered. In other words, S3 is adding more servers to handle your prefixes in order to meet your demand. However, the partitions need some time to be provisioned. You will still get 503s until the partitions are fully provisioned.

You can open a support ticket to ask them to provision more partitions in advance :)

Comment: We will be doing performance testing to determine the number of partitions before going to production, but I need to know how to handle these spikes.  I'm assuming you're suggesting to retry and let the SDK's back-off logic have another go at it?  And would TranferManager make this case better or worse?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Java SDK. In my experience with Python, retry with exponential back-off is probably good enough.